# Neo4j GraphQL library schema instrospector wtih property names separated by a dot

Tags: neo4j, graphql, neo4j-graphql-js, neo4j-graphql-library

I use the following code in order to automatically introspect the existent Neo4j schema:

```
import { toGraphQLTypeDefs } from "@neo4j/introspector";
import fs from "fs";
import neo4j from "neo4j-driver";

const driver = neo4j.driver(
    "neo4j://localhost:7687",
    neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j")
);

const sessionFactory = () => driver.session({ defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.READ })

async function main() {
    const typeDefs = await toGraphQLTypeDefs(sessionFactory)
    fs.writeFileSync('schema.graphql', typeDefs)
    await driver.close();
}
main()
```

On the existent Neo4j database it produces the following:

```
type BaseEntity10 @node(labels: ["BaseEntity", "CompanyType", "CompositeEntity", "Requirable"]) {
    baseEntity16SCompanyTypeOf: [BaseEntity16!]! @relationship(type: "COMPANY_TYPE_OF", direction: IN)
    createdAt: BigInt!
    createdByBaseEntity4S: [BaseEntity4!]! @relationship(type: "CREATED_BY", direction: OUT)
    id: BigInt!
    lowerName: String!
    name: String!
    nameSlug: String!
    properties.lowerNameMonolithic: String!
    properties.lowerNameWhitespace: String!
    status: String!
    system: Boolean!
    updatedAt: BigInt!
    uuid: String!
}
```

The issue is with the following definitions:

```
properties.lowerNameMonolithic: String!
properties.lowerNameWhitespace: String!
```

In the https://graphql-toolbox.neo4j.io/ when I try to build this schema, I receive the error:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected character: ".".
Locations: [{"line":24,"column":12}]
```

How to properly introspect existing properties with names separated by a dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL only allows alphanumeric characters and underscores in [names](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blame/October2021/spec/Section%202%20--%20Language.md#L191).

If your graph data model has property names containing special symbols like ".", you should consider changing those property names to conform to the GraphQL requirements (e.g., "properties_lowerNameMonolithic" instead of "properties.lowerNameMonolithic").